# Check if javascript object is part of javascript object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am creating a JavaScript game which is very similar to classic arcade Snake game.
For every piece of food snake eats it gets +1 on its size starting with size 5.
It is contained in canvas of 450X450 px with the size of one cell 10x10 px (picture).

[image]

The original game is taken and modified from another source, but my goal is to create autopilot.

This is the function that generates food

```
    function create_food() {

    food = {
        x: Math.round(Math.random() * (w - cw) / cw),
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * (h - cw) / cw),
    };
}
```

Basically it is random number from 0 to width_of_canvas - snake_cell / snake_cell ((450-10)/10).
So food has coordinate x and coordinate y. On very similar principle are the snake cells but it is an array with all the snake cells.

```
    function create_snake() {
    snake_array = []; //Empty array to start with
    length = 5;
    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //This will create a horizontal snake starting from the top left
        snake_array.push({
            x: i,
            y: 0
        });
    }
}
```

Only difference is there are multiple fields in snake array while there is only one in food array.

**PROBLEM:**
I don't want food spawning INSIDE my snake, so I need to check if the coordinates of the food would be same as one of the fields in snake array.

I was thinking of inArray() function but I don't know how to use it in this case.

**EXAMPLE:**
food[0].x = 31; food[0].y = 22

- snake_array[0].x = 28; snake_array[0].y = 22
- snake_array[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA8Uu.jpg)].x = 29; snake_array[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA8Uu.jpg)].y = 22
- snake_array[2].x = 30; snake_array[2].y = 22
- **snake_array[3].x = 31; snake_array[3].y = 22** collision
- snake_array[4].x = 32; snake_array[4].y = 22

EDIT: thanks @Siguza

Comment: Would't it be enough to create first the snake with complete freedom, and then create the food pieces taking care not to be included in the snake array?

Comment: @LittleSanti yes, thats actually what I'm doing, but again food needs to check if its coordinates collide with the snake, so again I need this method.

Comment: @Siguza this question explains comparison of 2 objects. But I need to check one object vs array of objects. EDIT: I could do this with for loop? Standby....

Comment: @user3188464 Yes, so you'd like to **compare an object** with every object in an array. I trust you know enough JS to add a loop yourself.

Comment: @user3188464 For what it's worth, here's a one-liner: `snake_array.map(function(e){return JSON.stringify(e)}).indexOf(JSON.stringify({x:31,y:22}))>-1`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [`lodash`](http://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) there's already a function to find if two objects are same:

```
_.isEqual(object, other);
```

And in your function, you can check for the `in_array();` equivalent in JavaScript.

```
function in_array(needle, haystack, argStrict) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: vlado houba
  // improved by: Jonas Sciangula Street (Joni2Back)
  //    input by: Billy
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //   example 1: in_array('van', ['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld']);
  //   returns 1: true
  //   example 2: in_array('vlado', {0: 'Kevin', vlado: 'van', 1: 'Zonneveld'});
  //   returns 2: false
  //   example 3: in_array(1, ['1', '2', '3']);
  //   example 3: in_array(1, ['1', '2', '3'], false);
  //   returns 3: true
  //   returns 3: true
  //   example 4: in_array(1, ['1', '2', '3'], true);
  //   returns 4: false

  var key = '',
    strict = !! argStrict;

  //we prevent the double check (strict && arr[key] === ndl) || (!strict && arr[key] == ndl)
  //in just one for, in order to improve the performance 
  //deciding wich type of comparation will do before walk array
  if (strict) {
    for (key in haystack) {
      if (haystack[key] === needle) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (key in haystack) {
      if (haystack[key] == needle) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

You can change the function where it says:

```
haystack[key] == needle
```

With the following:

```
_.isEqual(haystack[key], needle)
```

Comment: This can be my last option, I believe that there could be a solution with only JavaScript/jquery

Comment: Yes, @user3188464 Do not reinvent the wheel.